# c++11 #include <thread> gives compile error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++, pthreads

I get a compile error when trying to create an object file from a compiled source file. I am using the  header which came with c++11. I am also using a c++ pattern recognition library with several other includes.

All I did was add `#include <thread>` to my rbm_test.cc source file.

My compile command:

> g++ -std=c++11  -O3 -DQUIET  -fPIC -pthread  -ansi -pedantic -DARCH_INTEL  -Wall -W -Wchar-subscripts -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-qual -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion -Wno-old-style-cast -Wctor-dtor-privacy -Wnon-virtual-dtor -I../src -I../..  -DPATREC -D_*UNIX*_ -o rbm_test.o -c ../src/rbm_test.cc

The compile error I get is:

> error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the
>   ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and
>   must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.

Strangely, when I compile the following code example with

> g++ -std=c++11 -pthread -c main.cpp -o main.o

then I have no error.

Here Is `main.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void f1()
{
  std::cout << "Thread  executing\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t1(f1);
    std::thread t2(f1);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

Is it possible that some of the compile flags are conflicting when I try to compile rbm_test.cc?

Comment: Ok so just as I posted the question I found the solution. The -ansi flag conflicts with the -std=c++11 flag. -ansi is equivalent to -std=c++98. Removing the -ansi flag solved the problem.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was about to suggest. You can post it as an answer and select it.

Comment: I may have missed it, but it would be a good idea to include the compiler version.

Comment: gcc 4.7 is the compiler version..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The -`ansi` flag conflicts with the `-std=c++11` flag. `-ansi` is equivalent to `-std=c++98`. Removing the `-ansi` flag solves the problem.