# Qt: CONFIG += C++11, but -std=c++0x

Tags: c++, c++11, mingw, qt-creator, qt5.1

When I compile a project under **Qt Creator 2.8 / Qt5.1** with VS 2010 all is fine. If I do the same with MinGW I get the following error.

```
 error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
```

I understand I need to enable C+11, but I have `CONFIG   += console c++11` in my .pro file. Is this not what is needed? **What am I doing wrong?**

When I look at the make I see:

```
CXXFLAGS      = -pipe -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -g -std=c++0x
```

Confusing, as I say c++11 in the pro file.

1. Have deleted everything, run `qmake` etc, from the scratch, no result
2. As said, with VS2010 it works
3. Using the MinGW with gcc 4.8.0 from here. http://qt-project.org/downloads
4. If this matters, Win7 32

Checked:

- No ANSI: [c++11 #include <thread> gives compile error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15632198/c11-include-thread-gives-compile-error)
- std=c+11 MinGW: [C++11 functionality with MinGW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16136142/c11-functionality-with-mingw/16144116#16144116)

Found solution, but can only accept it in some time: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19530028/356726

Comment: It's the same thing, except `-std=c++0x` also works with older versions of the compiler.

Comment: Thanks. But why the "must be enabled with the -std=c++11" error when I use #include <type_traits>

Comment: That is indeed weird.

Comment: Are you sure that gcc 4.8.0 is being picked up (maybe some other distro you have on the machine is being found).  As @R.MartinhoFernandes says, gcc should treat `-std=c++0x` and `-std=c++11` the same. You might try adding `-v` to the `CXXFLAGS` to get details on exactly which compiler and which include directories are being used.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enable c++11 in qt creator 2.7.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16948382/how-to-enable-c11-in-qt-creator-2-7-0)

Comment: No, it is not a duplicate. The other question was asking about enabling C++11 in general. I did enable C++11 the correct way, but missed it in a subproject. This caused some kind of weird error and caused some kind of confusion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, thanks to your hints I have figured it out.

After I have tried any possible advice from above, with still no success, I have excluded any subproject I could think of in my project. Eventually I have found a QML sample .pro which did not have `CONFIG   += c++11` defined.

That was causing the error. So the root cause was not the project I was working on, but a subproject which however got compiled in the same step.

Answer (score 9):

Try changing the `mkspecs/win32-g++/qmake.conf` line that says:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_CXX11    = -std=c++0x
```

to:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_CXX11    = -std=c++11
```

and re-run qmake.

---

Some additional details:

Adding the "c++11" feature to the `CONFIG` qmake variable causes the `mkspecs/features/c++11.prf` file to be pulled in (see the "Adding New Configuration Features" section of the [qmake Advanced Usage](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/qmake-advanced-usage.html) document for details).

That qmake profile has a `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += $$QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_CXX11` line among other things which configure C++11 support. So adding "c++11" to the CONFIG variable is the proper way to indicate that you want c++11 support to qmake, as you mentioned in a comment.

Comment: With the latest QtCreator under Ubuntu 14.04, I still have the same issue (albeit at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/common/g++-base.conf).  I find it a bit alarming that I have to edit the installed conf file to get this to work.  Is there a way for user config or pro/pri files to redefine this variable?

Comment: I don't know - I'm not knowledgeable enough with qmake to know if there's a user-accessible mechanism to override this.

Answer (score 7):

I am using Qt Creator 2.7.2, and I have this line in my .pro file:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: I will give this a trail. Somewhere I have read not to use QMAKE_CXXFLAGS but CONFIG += c++11 - but I cannot recall. Will update as soon as I have a result.

Answer (score 1):

qmake will use whatever flags one has for c++11.  So you can overwrite them like:

unix:QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_CXX11  = -std=c++11

CONFIG          *= c++11

You can even tell it to use -std=c++14 or -std=c++17 instead when c++11 is added to the config as older qmake's might not be aware of them.